# How would you export NServiceBus's NHibernate Saga mappings?

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus, nservicebus5

We use the NServiceBus generated NHibernatePersistence mappings for our Sagas. I'd like to take a look at these mappings to help diagnose a problem and potentially serve as a starting point for some tweaks that we may need to make to these mappings.

With something like FluentNHibernate I could use an ExportTo method in order to dump out the generated hbm files. Is there something similar that I could use to dump out the default mappings that nservicebus is using for our sagas? Or is there some other way to go about exporting the generated mappings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ScriptGenerator` class as shown in this [test](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.NHibernate.Tests/GenerateSciptsTest.cs). Combined with something like ApprovalTests, `ScriptGenerator` can make sure that the schema changes are always explicitly approved.

Comment: This sent me down a path to get what I needed. I pulled down the NServiceBus.NHibernate source, referenced it directly, added this line...

var xml = modelMapper.Compile().AsString();

... inside the NHibernateSagaStorage class along with a breakpoint, which allowed me to grab a copy of the hbm that was generated.
Thank you!

Comment: With `ScriptGenerator` you don't need to compile from the sources. But grabbing the sources is also a valid option.